# The system running on low graphics mode and unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, dependencies, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

getting error while login

> The system is running on low graphics mode

I have tried almost all the possible solutions, but nothing worked.
tried purging and removing gdm, gdm removed but not installing.
[image]

For these unmet dependencies I  tried everything. like autoclean, dpkg configure -a, sudo apt-get install -f, sudo apt-get update ...

I had also tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

but getting same, unmet dependencies

Comment: Can you copy the output of the command that you are showing in your image and paste it to your question.  That will make it easier to read.  We will also be able to easier copy and paste the errors to google to help find how the errors were resolved for others.

Comment: Cannot copy, posting question from other laptop.